# tlsh не вычисляет хэш

Tags: python, хеширование

Собрал [tlsh](https://github.com/trendmicro/tlsh) для python из исходников:

```
py_ext>python setup.py build
py_ext>python setup.py install
```

Тестирую. В readme сказано, что

> For example, tlsh.hash(str(os.urandom(256))), should always generate a hash.

```
>>> import tlsh
>>> import os
>>> tlsh.hash(str(os.urandom(256)))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот так:

```
tlsh.hash(os.urandom(256))
```